# Lots of syntax errors in HAML view (using spree engine)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, spree

I have this simple HAML view, `admin.html.haml`:

```
!!!
%html{:xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}
  %head{"data-hook" => "admin_inside_head"}
```

(the view is quite large, I deleted most of it for clarity)

Going to `http://localhost:3000/admin` I get:

```
SyntaxError in Spree/admin/overview#index

Showing /Users/panayi/Dropbox/Sites/RAILS/engines/core/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.haml where line #2 raised:

/Users/panayi/Dropbox/Sites/RAILS/engines/core/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.haml:2: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
...ut.attributes({}, nil, :xmlns =&gt; "http://www.w3.org/1999/...
...                               ^
/Users/panayi/Dropbox/Sites/RAILS/engines/core/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.haml:2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '}'
..."http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")}>\n  <head#{_hamlout.adjust_...
...                               ^
/Users/panayi/Dropbox/Sites/RAILS/engines/core/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.haml:3: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
...tributes({}, nil, "data-hook" =&gt; "admin_inside_head")}></...
...                               ^
/Users/panayi/Dropbox/Sites/RAILS/engines/core/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.haml:3: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '}'
...ook" =&gt; "admin_inside_head")}></head>\n</html>\n", -1, fa...
...                               ^
/Users/panayi/Dropbox/Sites/RAILS/engines/core/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.haml:3: unknown regexp options - htl
/Users/panayi/Dropbox/Sites/RAILS/engines/core/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.haml:3: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...nside_head")}></head>\n</html>\n", -1, false);::Haml::Util.h...
...                               ^
/Users/panayi/Dropbox/Sites/RAILS/engines/core/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.haml:3: unterminated string meets end of file
/Users/panayi/Dropbox/Sites/RAILS/engines/core/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.haml:3: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: !!!
2: %html{:xmlns =&gt; "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}
3:   %head{"data-hook" =&gt; "admin_inside_head"}
Trace of template inclusion: /Users/panayi/Dropbox/Sites/RAILS/engines/core/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.haml
```

---

The haml gem is loaded correctly (messing with the haml view indentation I get a Haml::SyntaxError), and it worked ok with erb views, before switching the spree views to haml.

Can anyone suggest what to check, to resolve the errors?

Comment: Strange, the syntax looks just fine.  In fact, I put it into my layout file and it rendered fine for me.  Granted, I'm not using Spree but that should make no difference I would presume.

Comment: By the way, in HAML, fixing one error normally fixes all errors.  So even though it's showing a ton of errors, it's probably only related to one thing (which I'm sorry to say I can't help you with).  You might want to try posting this question to the HAML google group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spotted the problem:

Spree uses [deface](https://github.com/railsdog/deface) which is incompatible with HAML (see [here](https://github.com/railsdog/deface/issues/4)).

The solution is to disable deface in the environment-specific config file (development.rb, production.rb, etc). Add this:

```
  # Disable deface
  config.deface.enabled = false
```